# Линии начала/конца функции в visual studio и настройки шрифта

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, vb.net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне понравился данный стиль написания кода. Я хочу применить подобное в своем проекте. Не понимаю, как изменить цвет шрифта в коде. И как создать такие же линии, обозначающие начало/конец функции?

Comment: @Kromster, visual studio 2017

Comment: А что именно в этом скриншоте вам нравится? Вы можете включить тему 'Dark' (Options - Environment - General - Color theme), поменяется вид шрифтов. Это то? Или что-то ещё нужно в шрифтах?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994258/5752652

Comment: @AK, я тему то поменял, меня другое интересует - цвет функций. Например, посмотрите на "GhostButton5_Click", она имеет желтый цвет, а у меня белый. Я посчитал, что это "особенность" языка, но, как оказалось, это не так. Смотрел код других людей и там таких цветов не было

Comment: Цвета шрифтов и т. п. заданы в цветовой теме Студии. Их множество, найдите и выберите подходящую. Где искать? [Color Themes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio) - на этом сайте.

Comment: _линии, обозначающие начало/конец функции_ - если имеются в виду горизонтальные сплошные линии, то они ставятся в коде Visual Basic. В C# их делать не принято.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что именно в этих шрифтах вам нравится, но начнём с базового.

Студия поставляется с темами оформления, выбрать нужную можно в Options - Environment - General - Color theme.

Линии обозначающие начало/конец функции [включаются](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994258/5752652) в Options - Text Editor - Basic - Advanced - Show procedure line separator (можно ввести часть названия настройки и вам отфильтрует разделы, в которых есть подобная настройка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> посмотрите на "GhostButton5_Click", она имеет желтый цвет, а у меня белый

Зайдите в Options - Environment - Fonts and Color и поправьте любой цвет, который вам нравится. Вероятно вам нужно смотреть определения для VB * или VbScript в первую очередь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я узнал, что происходит. Я запустил проект в visual studio 2019. Там именно такая подсветка и используется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эту подсветку использовать в Visual studio 2017? все шрифты попробовал, не подходит

Comment: @lordd18 Попробуйте поискать может уже есть готовые темы среди расширений студии, но вообще самый логичный вариант - поставьте себе поверх 2017 студии ещё и 2019 и постепенно привыкайте работать с ней.